# Site used to search for web scrapers and copyright infringement

Tags: webapp-rec, copyright

When I was working for a smaller company a few years ago, I discovered a site that would parse your own site and use that to search the web for other sites that are copying your content.  It was made more to find scrapers but I was able to use it to find sites that were actually copying the copyright protected content and passing it off as their own.

I can't for the life of me remember what it's called.  Does anyone use something similar or have any idea what this is called?

Answer (score 1):

Are you thinking of

http://www.copyscape.com/

> Copyscape provides a free plagiarism checker for finding copies of your web pages online, as well as two more powerful professional solutions for preventing content theft and content fraud ....